# Arithmetic and geometric progressions

Tags: sequences-and-series

The product of three numbers in a geometric progression is 1000. If we add 6 to its second number and 7 to its third number, the resulting three numbers form an arithmetic progression. find the numbers in GP . I fail to find the answer

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Take the numbers as $a/r$, $a$, $ar$, you will get $a^3=1000$ by product of terms
So, $a=10$
 Now use $(10r + 7)+ \frac{10}{r} = 2(10+6)$
(since numbers are in AP) $\quad$to find $r$.